# Access to atributes from derived class in the base class

Tags: java, inheritance

In my spring project, I add this generic class to provide to my entity classes some common methods used by all of them:

```
public abstract class object implements Comparable<object> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int compareTo(object arg0, int ordem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

In the second method, I need a way to the derived class use the atribute indicated by ordem to perform the comparation (to be implemented).

By example, if the derived class is this:

```
public class Usuario extends object {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    ...

}
```

then the value for ordem would be:

1=login, 2=senha, 3=first_name, 4=last_name, 5=email.

Anyone knows if this is possible and how to do if the answer was yes?

Comment: Store the values in an ArrayList or HashMap in the parent class instead of as raw variables?

Comment: The problem with this solution it's the parent class is the base class for all the entity classes. I need, by example, if ordem == 1, compare the two objects by the first argument, if ordem == 2, by the second, and if ordem > number of arguments of the derived class, return -1.

Comment: I think you are complicating, every object has a different ways of `comparison` and why are you trying to `generalise` ..

Comment: The only easy way for the parent class to know about the data in the child class is if the parent class stores the data and the child just updates the parent's data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this: Add an abstract method to your base class:

```
protected abstract Object getArgument(int ordem);
```

You still have to implement it in every inheriting class but you could generalize the comparison logic. The implementation for your example would look like this:

```
protected abstract Object getArgument(int ordem) {
     switch(ordem) {
     case 1: return login;
     case 2: return senha;
     case 3: return first_name;
     case 4: return last_name;
     case 5: return email;
     default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ordem " + ordem);
     }
}
```